# iOS UIDatePicker time zone issue

Tags: iphone, ios, timezone, uidatepicker

I am having a very frustrating timezone issue with UIDatePicker.

When I initialise my date picker I set the time zone to the system time zone to allow the app to be used in multiple countries

```
[datePicker setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

Then a user selects a date. On saving the date (saved in CoreData) the date that comes back from the date picker is correct but then I want to just get the date and not the time i.e. with a time of 00:00:00

When I choose a date in GMT (not in BST) the date works fine. If I select date in BST (March - October) I get the date back as 1 hour behind.

This is how I am pulling the date out

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *dateOfBirth = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:      [dobDatePicker date]]];
```

I checked and the system time is definitly GMT, so then why does the value of dateOfBirth come back wrong

i.e

```
[dobDatePicker date] = "1991-05-30 18:58:16 +0000"
dateOfBirth          = "1991-05-29 23:00:00 +0000"
```

Any suggestions? I dont want to force the timezone as I want it to run off the phones time zone.

Reason I am not interested in the time is I am storing this date as a date of birth and use it to calculate values like age and number of seconds until your birthday so dont want the current time from the date picker in the date I store in CoreData

Thanks

Comment: So I tried to simply things here and just used a hard coded date in a formatter and get the same issue:  
  
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];  
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];  
    NSDate *dateOfBirth = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1968-05-31"];  
    NSLog(@"%@",dateOfBirth);  
  
This outputs:  
  
2013-03-30 22:56:33.460: 1968-05-30 23:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 2):

Use the following when fetching the time instead and let me know if it works for you.

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```

This will return the phone's time zone always. I think systemTimeZone might be bugged. Cheers.